# Draw ellipse in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

For the parametric equation of an ellipse, which owns the following style:

> [image]

Or which could be written as matrix form

> [image]

Now I want to draw it by the coefficient matrix `[a b c; d e f]` in MATLAB

**Method 1**:`plot`

```
function drawEllipse1(mat)
    t = linspace(0,2*pi,101);
    vec = [sin(t); cos(t); ones(1,length(t))];

    %calculate the coordinates of ellipse
    ellipse = mat1*vec;
    ellipseX = ellipse(1,:);
    ellipseY = ellipse(2,:);
    plot(ellipseX,ellipseY)

end
```

**Method 2**:`ezplot`

```
function drawEllipse2(mat)
    syms t;
    ellipseExpr = mat*[sin(t); cos(t); 1];
    %pass a function handle
    ezplot(@(t)ellipseExpr(1),@(t)ellipseExpr(2),[0,2*pi])

end
```

However, `drawEllipse2()`cannot draw a ellipse normally? I didn't know why.

```
mat = [1 2 3;4 5 6];
drawEllipse2(mat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely sure, but i think its because how you are passing that function handle. 
If you were to simply do:

```
ezplot(ellipseExpr(1),ellipseExpr(2),[0,2*pi])
```

you get the same ellipse. 
[image]